# Return URL Whenever a Client Requests a Page

Tags: javascript, html, http

I'm pretty new to JavaScript and I'm trying to send data from an ESP8266 to my Github Pages through simple URL data. To send data, the ESP will just try to connect to "mygithubpages.com?DATA." On the server side, I'm trying to get the DATA portion of that URL and use it. Hopefully, this is clear but if not I'd be glad to clarify. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your goal is to retrieve GET params of your page's url. If so, then `window.location.search` will contain `?DATA` in your case and if your goal is to get only `DATA` then use `window.location.search.substr(1)`